# React-Router 3 Error: <Route> elements are for router configuration only and should not be rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I try create SPA but I get the error. It works only with incorrect url for 404 page

Uncaught Error:  elements are for router configuration only and should not be rendered

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuGB0.png)

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import {Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from './store/configureStore'

import Full from './containers/Full/'
import LoginPage from './containers/LoginPage/'
import Page404 from './views/Pages/Page404/'
import Dashboard from './views/Dashboard/';

const store = configureStore()

ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}> 
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <div>
        <Route path="/" component={Full}>
            <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path='dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path='login' component={LoginPage} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='*' component={Page404} />     
        </div>  
    </Router>
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: remove the `/` in the imports. it should be `import Full from './containers/Full'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const store = configureStore()
const routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={Full}>
       <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />
       <Route path='dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
       <Route path='login' component={LoginPage} />
       <Route path='*' component={Page404} />
     </Route>

 );

const App = (
   <Provider store={store}> 
      <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
    </Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(App, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: We'll need to see a better description of the error, you could screenshot it and share here

Comment: I added screenshot

Comment: I just modified the answer above, take a look @IlyaHmurovich

Comment: which version of `react-router` are you using?

Comment: "react-router": "^3.2.0"

Comment: Let me see your import statements @IlyaHmurovich, I am sure something must be wrong with the way you import `Route`

Comment: See a similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901309/error-route-elements-are-for-router-configuration-only-and-should-not-be-rend)

Comment: I added import statements